# Magento store dependent text

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento multi store and a lot of my pages are equal so I'm using these pages for both my stores. There's just one problem: the phonenumber prefix is different and therefor I want to show in store1 prefix 057 and in store1 prefix 0057.
You see it's a minor detail and I don't want to use double pages based on this so is there a way to show store dependent text?

Comment: This question might be better asked on http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CMS blocks with the different prefixes for each store, or if you can afford to create your own module, you could use a system config field and add this in your CMS pages : `{{config path='path/to_your/field'}}`